# pass two arguments on button clicked (access two strings on button click)

Tags: iphone, ios

I am a new Programmer of i phone

i have a little problem.... i wants pass two arguments on button click....

```
//---insert individual row into the table view---

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell %i",indexPath.section]];

    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell %i",indexPath.section]] autorelease];

    }


    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;//my code.... change the color or selected cell



    search_items *pro = [searchCount objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];


        NSString *string1=[[NSString alloc]init];
    NSString *string2=[[NSString alloc]init];


       /// i wants access these two strings on buttonClicked Method...(pass as a argument):)

    string1=pro.s_showroomName;

        string2=pro.s_productName;


       UIButton* aButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

    aButton.frame = CGRectMake(150, 15,150,40); 

    [aButton setTag:indexPath.row];

        [aButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        [cell.contentView addSubview:aButton];

    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];

        [aButton setImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [aButton setTitle:@"View Details" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [aButton addSubview:buttonLabel1];


    NSString *filepath=[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:pro.s_image ofType:@"png"];

        UIImage *image=[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filepath];



    cell.imageView.image=image;



    return cell;
}

-(void)buttonClicked:(UIButton*)sender {

    //int tag = sender.tag;


}
```

Comment: What do you mean by pass two arguments? Do you want information contained by your cell to be accessible in the button callback?

Comment: @jbat...thanks for giving me your valuable time........yes.. i wants access information contained by cell...in my method buttonClicked...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple method to access your cell from the button, in the button callback is to ask it for it's superview's superview:

```
-(void)buttonClicked:(UIButton*)sender {

    //int tag = sender.tag;
    UIView* contentView = [sender superview];
    if ([[contentView superview] isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]] == NO) {
        NSLog(@"Unexpected view hierarchy");
        return;
    }
    UITableViewCell* cell = (UITableViewCell*)[contentView superview];

}
```

You can also, based on the frame of the button, find out which cell it belongs to in the table view. You would need to convert the frame from the button to the table view (UIView has methods to do the conversion).

The default UITableViewCell objects have a textLabel and a detailTextLabel, in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method you can set their text like this:

```
cell.textLabel.text = @"Some text";
cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Some detail text";
```

then you can access these properties in your callback, when you have obtained the cell.

Comment: ...i wants add two labels in my table cell...(showroomName and ProductName) and access showroomName.text and ProductName.text in my ButtonClicked method......can you give me little code....(thanks in advance)

Comment: Added some code for the default labels, and also a check that the superview's superview is indeed a UITableViewCell, to avoid nasty surprises.